# referencing several tables in one reference

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I need to reference several tables like Tables 1-3 or Tables 3.1 to 3.3 related with the section, I'm using the normal `\ref{table1,table2,table3}` to do what I want, but when I compile I get something like `???` Could someone tell me how to solve this little problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: You should use the `cleveref` package for that: the `\cref` command compresses and sorts references automatically.  It even saves you typing the word ‘tables’ whatever your language (well, a number of languages).

Comment: The ??? means the reference value is missing, which is sometimes solved by recompiling.

Comment: If you don't want to use the package, you can write "see Tables \ref{table1}--\ref{table3}."

Comment: @Tim I would rather write "see Tables~\ref{table1}\nobreakdash--\ref{table3}". Better rendering :-)

Answer (score 12):

As already suggested in one of the comments, to achieve your objective you should load the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) package and type

```
\cref{table1,table2,table3}
```

Assuming these tables are numbered 1, 2, and 3, respectively, and assuming you're writing in English, you'll get

> Tables 1--3

where "--" is supposed to represent an en-dash. (The conjuction particle is actually configurable; if one states `\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{ to~}` in the preamble, one would get "Tables 1 to 3" instead of `Tables 1--3`.)

Note that you needn't actually enter the labels in consecutive order; if you'd written `\cref{table2,table3,table1}`, you'd still have gotten "Tables 1--3".

The package does impose an important restriction on the characters permitted in labels: since `,` is used as the separator between labels that form the the argument of `\cref`, you can't use `,` as a component of a label.

Comment: One can also use the `\crefrange{table1}{table3}` command to achieve a similar effect without having to type all of the objects between

Comment: @darthbith - The example I gave simply copied the setup given by the OP. For `\crefrange{table1}{table3}` to give the same result as `\cref{table2,table3,table1}`, one would also have to assume that there are no other tables in the range given by the lowest and higest `table` number. This may or may not be a valid assumption, right?

Comment: Correct, `\crefrange` simply produces a consecutive range. Of course `\cref` and `\crefrange` do the same thing in this case, and in this case one can be more explicit (or save some typing for a very large range of objects) if it is wished :-)