# How to cite several tables in one reference?

Tags: cross-referencing

I have met a simple problem. I want to reference several tables in one reference. My code is as below. I learned from the former thread at "[referencing several tables in one reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200201/referencing-several-tables-in-one-reference)". But it still turned wrong with error like "?????". 
If I use the command, `\crefrange{test1}{test3}`. It turns right. But I want to display the label like "Figs." instead of "figs". 
Could anyone do me a favor? Thanks!

```
`\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}`
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{fontspec,cleveref}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\usepackage{indentfirst,amsmath,multicol,amssymb,booktabs,threeparttable,tabularx}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=normal,up,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1.4in,bottom=1.in,left=1in,right=1in}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{to~}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig} 
\graphicspath{{F:/}}
\begin{document}
\cref{test1, test2,test3 }

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=4.2in]{test1}\label{test1}}
 \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=4.2in]{test2}\label{test2}}
 \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=5in]{test3}\label{test3}} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where are the labels to `test1`, `test2`  and `test3`? This is like sending a letler without writing an address on the envelope.

Comment: Sorry, I will add it up.

Comment: Would you mind to learn how to properly mark up code on this site?

Comment: Where can I get it? Sorry! I disturb you a lot!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 5):

[image: chyhReferenceTables]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{~to~}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
%\usepackage{mwepage}% 4 line local package to get a yellow page
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Wombat}\label{wombat}
    \caption{Capybara}\label{capy}
    \caption{Mara}\label{mara}
\end{figure}
\Crefrange{wombat}{mara} and alternatively
\crefrange{wombat}{mara}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't correspond to the last line in the image.

Comment: @Bernard This is what my outdated TL2015 gives me. Please correct the image/screenshot or provide another answer.

Comment: Of course i forgot to delete the line loading `mwepage`.

Comment: I have nothing to add to your answer. I think you probably had a wrong copy-past on posting: if the end of the code is `\crefrange`, you should obtain `figs`, not `Figs`.

Comment: @Bernard I explicitely load `cleveref` with the option `capitalize`  to get `Figs.` as this is what the OP wanted.

Comment: I see. However,  it doesn't work on my system (perhaps because I have a cleveref.cfg in a local texmf root?).

Comment: I can confirm the output is the same with TL2017